# Update problems when updating to Varbase

Tags: 8, updating

I updated a Drupal 8 site to Varbase release 16. After running update.php I get the following error.

> Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException: Route "content_lock_timeout.settings_form" does not exist. in Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteProvider->getRouteByName() (line 190 of core\lib\Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteProvider.php).

Has anybody a idea how to proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The https://www.drupal.org/project/varbase/issues/2953417 shows Varbase is using [Content locking](https://www.drupal.org/project/content_lock) module, which is causing the reported error. Try temporarily disabling it to proceed.